# How do I fix this Visual Studio keyboard mapping problem?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

Something (who knows, possibly even me, though certainly not intentionally) has changed the keyboard mapping in Visual Studio **2008**, and I cannot figure out how to get it back to the default.

The symptom that I see as the problem is that when I type the name of a class which is not in a namespace listed in the using statements at the top of the file, **the shortcut to add that namespace to the file (expand tooltip), which is, by default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period) has been changed to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.** There are probably other key settings changed, but this is one that is really annoying me at the moment.

### Ways I have already tried to fix the problem which have not worked

- Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard, press Reset button. (The additional mapping scheme is set to Default, but I have also tried VC #2005; neither fixed the problem.)
- Tools, Import and Export Settings, re-import C# developer settings
- `devenv /reset`
- Using "repair" from the installer.

I know that I could probably fix just this one key binding by customizing it, but I don't want to do that. I want to reset **all** of the key binding spec to their default settings.

Comment: If nothing works, insert your CD click repair and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: Dirk, I've done that, too, but forgot to mention it. Unfortunately, it did not fix the problem. Thank you for commenting, though! I will update the post to mention this.

Comment: I have the same problem on several computers. Keyboard changes to English (US) when pressing Shift+Alt+F10. Not always, but sometimes.

Comment: @Craig: Are you saying that you can't use CTRL + . anymore?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: So it is not that it changed from CTRL+. to to Shift+Alt+F10 (as stated in your post). It's that CTRL+. stopped working.
You said you don't want to customize it, but have you at least tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Yes it does. I figured out the problem, though. See solution below.

Comment: Bad question! Why would you want to reset them back to default ? I want it to **STOP** resetting the keyboard settings back which it does on **very random** occasions!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the problem: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> was remapped by FSI when I installed F#. That's why resetting the key mappings didn't fix the issue: I still had F#. And the answer to which other mappings I've lost is, "Those mapped by FSI" (type FSI in keyboard mappings; there are only two).

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem, (Tools-Options->Keyboard) `View.ShowSmartTag` is the field where you can re-assign the shortcut manually to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

I know it's a few months post date, but that should do the trick.

Comment: I think you're right, but it only fixes the one key. +1 for effort, though.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a "working" visual studio around? You can export the setting (keyboard only settings) from that machine and import it into your machine.

Answer (score 2):

In the default Visual Studio 2008 C# key bindings, both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> map to Show Smart Tag.

You can download Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Did you do something like install [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

If you did, you can fix this by going through your options for Visual Studio and/or the options for ReSharper (Can't remember now) and simply setting them up to continue using Visual Studio Layouts as opposed to that of the Add-in.

Comment: No, I've never installed Resharper, or any other third-party add-in. The only things I've added to Visual Studio have been Microsoft releases such as ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

something that happen to me ...
make sure that "F lock" key on the keyboard (if you one of this) is on.. i didn't sew that i turn it off, and nothing work normal. (F5 - open the open dialog, F10 switch to split mode!)